# Unter dem/den/. Einfluss

Tags: dative, accusative

Although the question is a duplicate, the answers here are also enlightening.

With Google I can find examples using e.g.

```
gerät unter dem Einfluss  
gerät unter den Einfluss  
gerät unter Einfluss
```

What is the difference?

Comment: This question is about the use of two-way prepositions / Wechselpräpositionen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verbs of movement together with prepositions for locality (*über, unter, an, in,...*) can rule either the accusative or the genitive.

**Accusative** denotes movement *towards* something, while **dative** denotes movement *within* something.

> Ich gehe in den Park

means I'm somewhere else and go towards the park

> Ich gehe im Park

means I'm already in the park and move about there

Same goes with *unter* and *über*

> Ich rette mich unter eine Brücke vor dem Unwetter

means I'm somewhere else and move under the bridge from the rain

> Während des Unwetters ging ich unter der Brücke auf und ab

maybe I was bored and walked about under the bridge to waste some time while it was raining.

Now to your example fragments (you really should provide a bit more context - As given, some of your fragments might or might not be wrong:

*geraten* as a verb of movement falls under the same rules as above.

> Jeden Tag geraten die Weltmeere unter dem Einfluß der Schwerkraft des Mondes in Bewegung

*Einfluß* stands in dative here, because there's no movement *towards something* - the influence of gravity of the moon applies all the time, constantly.

> Geraten Jugendliche unter den Einfluß fundmentalistischer Strömungen, kann es sein, dass sie sich extrem schnell radikalisieren.

This is definitely a movement *towards the influence* - thus accusative.

> Geraten Jugendliche unter Einfluss fundamentalistischer ...

is accusative as well (after all, it is the same sentence) - The main difference is that "Einfluß" is now handled as an *uncountable* which means it can come without a definite or indefinite article.

> Unter Einfluß von Alkohol sollte man nicht Auto fahren.

Comment: Actually, "gerät unter den Einfluss" is not a movement _toward_ something, but more properly a movement _into_ something (which uses the accusative as well, of course). Also I think you should point out that "gerät unter dem Einfluss" is not even a phrase (_unter..._ ist kein Präpositionalobjekt), while "gerät unter dem Einfluss" is.

Comment: @sgf I cannot see that either "...unter dem Einfluss" or "...unter den Einfluss" are phrases at all - Both are fragments that can be used to form a proper sentence (see examples). And "unter" is definitely not "into".

Answer (score 1):

> gerät unter dem Einfluss
>
> gerät unter den Einfluss

Indeed both variants are correct but they do have a different meaning:

Nearly any verb can be combined with "*unter dem Einfluss*" to indicate that something happens while or because something different has an influence:

> Er fuhr das Auto **unter dem Einfluss** von Alkohol.
>
> He drove the car being under the influence of alcohol.

This also possible with the verb "*geraten*":

> Er **gerät unter dem Einfluss** von Alkohol an die Leitplanke.

The other variant is a fixed expression:

> unter **den** Einfluss ... geraten

This expression means that something or someone was not under the influence of something before and now is getting under that influence. Example:

> Der Politiker **gerät unter den Einfluss** der Lobbyvertreter.
>
> The politician is getting under the influence of the lobbyists.

The following expression might be used as shortcut for both variants:

> gerät unter Einfluss

However **I** would mainly use it as shortcut for "***dem** Einfluss*":

> Er **gerät unter Einfluss** von Alkohol an die Leitplanke.

---

Just to make it more difficult:

I said nearly any verb can be combined with "*unter dem Einfluss*". This is also true for "*unter den Einfluss geraten*":

> Der Politiker gerät unter **dem** Einfluss von Bestechungsgeldern unter **den** Einfluss der Lobbyisten.